# Asp.net Can't create view IEnumerable<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm following a book about C# (Pro asp.net MVC 3 Framework) It is a little out dated but there's not much difference compared to the newer versions.

Ebook: [Ebook version, google link.](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CCoQFjABahUKEwiX27PyuOTHAhUL8RQKHX8bAME&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcommerce1.googlecode.com%2Ffiles%2FPro.ASP.NET.MVC.3.Framework.pdf&usg=AFQjCNGiX30BgMOYT4SpTEqyWbWozVE0Fg&sig2=B_TU7ZwTFTa80CifP43Xvw&bvm=bv.102022582,d.bGQ&cad=rja)
I have the paper version of the book, but the page numbering is the same.
I got stuck at page 205, it asks me to create a view named 'Menu' and with the model class `IEnumerable<string>` I can't create that, when I enter that I cannot click on 'ADD'

According to the book:

[image: Image from book]

According to my editor:

[image: Image from my editor.]

I'm new to C# but I'll paste some of my code to let you guys understand it better.

```
{
    public class NavController : Controller
    {
      private IProductRepository repository;
      public NavController(IProductRepository repo)
      {
        repository = repo;
      }

      public PartialViewResult Menu() //Krijg hier geen VIEW met: "IEnumerable<string>" als Modelclass.
      {
        IEnumerable<string> categories = repository.Products
                                 .Select(x => x.Category)
                                 .Distinct()
                                 .OrderBy(x => x);
        return PartialView(categories);
      }
    }
}
```

Hopefully it's just something silly I did wrong.

Tips&adjustments are welcome!

Best regards

Comment: You can always create the view without specifying to model class and then just add it manually - `@model IEnumerable<string>`

Comment: Thanks, it was just a silly thing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create a view then specify the `Model`:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>
@foreach (var str in Model)
{
   <li>
      @Html.LabelFor(m => str, "My Label")
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => str)
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => str)
   </li>
}
```

So as [Stephen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3559349/stephen-muecke) mentioned there's no need to specify the modal that way.

Comment: Thanks, I marked this as the answer because I cannot vote a comment as an answer. This solved it.